# Named Pipe between C# and python

Tags: c#, python, named-pipes

I am trying to communicate between my C# code and my python script.

My problem is the following I would like to open a pipe at the beginning of my C# script and send information at different moments, but through the same previous pipe. And then process this data in my python script.

For now I can just send one information and then my pipe in C# closes itself. I tried these code to test:

[C# code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZLEk.png)

However, when I try this, my python scripts receives data only when I shutdown the C# code. If you have a solution please help me.

Comment: Include your code in your question as text, not image. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please also add a real code example to your question, not an image of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sw.Flush();` after each WriteLine to force it to flush the stream

Comment: It changes Nothing :/